# Why doesn't my code loading links in a browser tab work?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find a link on a website and open the link in a new tab. If I hide my code in comments and just tell it to open the link in a new tab in chrome it works but add the if statement back and it acts like it isn't finding what I know is in the source code. Any ideas?

```
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url='https://twitter.com/nikestore'
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    tag.get('href')
    if tag.has_attr('http://t.co/'):
       link=tag
       webbrowser.open_new_tab(link)
```

Comment: Please post this in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @justderb: there are obvious bugs in the code. Codereview requires working code, this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the whole `Element` (`<a href="...">`) around here.  You forgot to *assign* the `tag.get('href')` result:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    link = tag.get('href')
    if 'http://t.co/' in link:
       webbrowser.open_new_tab(link)
```

You can simplify your loop a little by using a regular expression match:

```
import re

for tag in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('^http://t\.co/')):
    link = tag['href']
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(link)
```